# strange token in: for(; max != 0 ; max/=10, pow10*=10)

Tags: c++, loops, syntax

```
for(; max != 0 ; max/=10, pow10*=10)
```

Pulled this exerpt from the wiki page on "Radix sort."  I've not seen a loop that starts with a semicolon like that before.  The compiler didn't catch it so I'm assuming it's legal.  Can anyone explain?

Also, as I've only written fairly simple loops I didn't realize that you could make multiple assignments (right word?) like "max/=10, pow10*=10" at the end of the for() statement ...  Is there any limit to this?  Bad form?

Thanks guys! (and pardon my potentially wrong vocabulary...it's early, I need more coffee...)

Comment: Well, any of them can be left blank. So `for(;;)` is legal as well (an infinite loop).

Comment: you can put as many expressions as you want in the init block and  step blocks of a for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly legal. This is a `for` loop with an empty initialization block.

The most typical `for` loop looks something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  ...
}
```

This is (almost) equivalent to the following:

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < size; ) {
  ...
  i++;
}
```

(Except that in the first case the scope of `i` is limited to within the loop, while in the second case, `i` is still visible after the loop, as its scope is the enclosing block.)

For loops have three blocks, separated by semicolons: *initialization*, *loop condition* and *loop increment*. Any or all of these can be empty. So this is legal too (resulting in an endless loop):

```
for(;;)
```

Answer (score 3):

> I've not seen a loop that starts with a semicolon like that before.

That just means that the initialiser clause is an empty expression - nothing is done before the first iteration. The other two clauses can be left blank too, if the loop you're writing doesn't need them. For example, `for (;;)` will loop forever, unless there is a `break`, `return`, `throw` or `goto` inside it.

> Is there any limit to this? Bad form?

The "comma operator" can be used to evaluate multiple expressions like that; there can be as many as you like, and they will be evaluated in order. It's often regarded as better form to use multiple statements, except in a case like this where only one statement is possible.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, you can execute multiple statements using the `comma operator`. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator for more information.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop has three elements separated by semicolons, all optional.

1. A statement to begin the loop
2. A condition to stay in the loop
3. A statement to execute after each loop iteration.

In this case, there's nothing executed before the first loop iteration, everything had already been done before.

For the last part, they're using the comma operator of C/C++: The comma operator means execute both statements, and return the last one. For example, `int x = 4,5;` is the same as `int x = 5;`. You can use this to run multiple statements where normally only one is allowed. The for loop you listed is one example, or you could do something like this with `if` statements.

```
char* s;
int compare;

if(s == NULL)
    ...
else if(compare = strcmp(s, otherString), compare < 0)
    ...
else if(compare > 0)
    ...
```

This is sometimes more readable than this:

```
if(s == NULL)
    ...
else
{
    compare = strcmp(s, otherString);
    if(compare < 0)
        ....
    else if(compare > 0)
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just an empty for init block. You can skip any part of the for loop, if there isn't anything to be done there (e.g. `for(;;)` is an infinite loop with no init and no epilogue).

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this is that the algorithm declares a variable before the loop, not inside the loop, so that it is also available outside the loop.

In this case, the reason is different. [The loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Example_in_C.2B.2B) uses **2** variables, `max` and `pow10`. However, the `for` loop allows zero or one declarations. For stylistic reasons, the coders put both declrations at the same place, directly before the `for` loop.